# How to debounce by ID in RxJS

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, reactive-programming

My problem is the next: I want to debounce the liking functionality of my app. I using actions to make changes in my app, for example:

```
dispatch(likePost(1)) // => dispatch({ type: 'LIKE_POST', id: 1 })
```

Given the next example:

I dispatch an action at time: 0

```
dispatch(likePost(1))
```

This gonna trigger my actionSource:

```
actionSource$.
   pipe(
      filter(isActionOf(likePost)),
      debounceTime(500)
      mapTo('make-api-request-to-like-the-post')
   )
```

So it's gonna looks like:

```
--DISPATCH(LIKE(1))---DEBOUNCE(500)---MAKE_API_CALL(1)---->
```

But there is a problem with this, as what happens if I make the next actions:

```
dispatch(likePost(1)) // at time 0ms
dispatch(likePost(2)) // at time 200ms
```

here we got a problem as the likePost(2) debounced the likePost(1), resulting only making a request with the likePost(2)

```
--DISPATCH(LIKE(1))--200ms--DISPATCH(LIKE(2))--DEBOUNCE(500)--MAKE_API_CALL(2)--->
```

So how could I debounce by id, or make it unique branches by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [groupBy](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy) events by `id` and then apply [debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) on each group individually.

For example:

```js
const { of } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { map, mergeMap, groupBy, debounceTime } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

of(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1).pipe(
  groupBy(id => id),
  mergeMap(likeById$ => 
    likeById$.pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
    )
  )
).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```